resolv.conf being stupid about local kvm domain
I'm trying to get DNS resolution to work for KVM/libvirt on a Debian 12 host with NM controlling the resolv.conf.
My isolated KVM guest network is 10.10.10.0/24 and "hostname -d" of my guests is "kvm".
If I edit (via nmtui or else) the corresponding bridge interface to query 10.10.10.1 as a DNS server for domain kvm, it adds "kvm" as a search domain and 10.10.10.1 as a nameserver, but "nslookup vm1" will return an error because it queries the public DNS servers first which don't know this.
So I wonder what options to feed to NM for its r.c generation like described here in order to be able to look up local ".kvm" stuff on 10.10.10.1 and everything else on public DNS.
#pseudo config:
search kvm
nameserver 10.10.10.1

search *
nameserver 8.8.8.8 (or whatever public DNS it uses automatically)

Second problem is, 10.10.10.1:53 is listening (libvirtd.service), but if I run "nslookup vm1 10.10.10.1", I actually get an error "refused". It does fill in the domain suffix correctly (I'm not sure if having multiple KVM domains would break this but that's a bit beyond my scope)

Depending on your needs, a better option might be to use the libvirt_guest NSS module, which makes libvirt guest names automatically resolvable from your vm host.

Thanks for the suggestion! I've found that it partially works, but gave me trouble with FQDN lookups, and only found the shortnames. Which I needed for a particular test so I had to stuff them into the hosts file; in a normal use case it's likely an irrelevant issue.
One thing to note is that while that link names the (yum) package as libvirt-nss, on debian-based systems, it seems to be called libnss-libvirt instead (for some reason)

resolv.conf does not support split DNS configuration. It does not matter how you order the lines (or how NetworkManager orders the lines), – it can only define one global pool of nameservers, and all of them are expected to equally answer all names, whether with the search suffix or not. The only purpose of the search parameter is to "auto-complete" unqualified names, not to organize disjoint groups of nameservers.
If you need to route requests differently according to their domain name, you'll need to point resolv.conf to a local resolver daemon that would be able to do that. NetworkManager has built-in support for doing so with either systemd-resolved or dnsmasq, although in both cases the configurations are grouped by interface, not arbitrarily. (Systemd-resolved alone has the same limitation, though dnsmasq does not.)
With such software, the only nameserver in your resolv.conf would be 127.0.0.x (plus a single list of search suffixes to attempt for auto-completion).
